# Css transition gradient to solid color

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm quite unsuccessful currently at creating a transition from a gradient to a solid color. Additionally, because of my gradient, I cannot seem to see my background image that's aligned to the right side.

Here's my code:

```
input {
    width: 306px;
     height:27px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    padding: 1px 30px 1px 9px;
    color: #767676;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 3px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     border-radius: 3px;
    border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/9hdsg.png');
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

    -moz-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -o-transition-property: width, background-color;
  transition-property: width, background-color;

  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;




    background: #787878; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #787878 0%, #787878 50%, #686868 51%, #797979 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#787878), color-stop(50%,#787878), color-stop(51%,#686868), color-stop(100%,#797979)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #787878 0%,#787878 50%,#686868 51%,#797979 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #787878 0%,#787878 50%,#686868 51%,#797979 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #787878 0%,#787878 50%,#686868 51%,#797979 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  #787878 0%,#787878 50%,#686868 51%,#797979 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#787878', endColorstr='#797979',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */


  }



input:focus {
  width: 535px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8neF9/2/

Thanks everybody :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. for multiple backgrounds to work you need to declare them in one line:
   `background: url(path/to/image), linear-gradient(...)` - first is the closest so it covers others.
2. to animate gradient to solid color, make a gradient twice as high (or long) as the element, so instead 50% use 25% etc.
3. background positions are also declared to in one line, same goes for repeat. In your case:

   ```
   background-size: 27px 29px, 100% 200%; // first image, then gradient twice as high
   background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat; // don't repeat image, repeat gradient
   ```
4. to animate gradient to solid color - use transition to change background position from: `background-position: 0 50%, 0 0;` to `background-position:0 50%, 0 100%`;

I've [upadted your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8neF9/3/), but didn't try to make it work with ie filter or old webkit syntax.

Comment: Wow great! Also, since we changed the background position, how can I align the image to the right?

Comment: Just change background position to `100% 50%, 0 100%`.